# Mirror Hard Drive To New Hard Drive

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, clone

I am needing to copy my exact hard drive set-up to a different hard drive, so I can place this drive in a different PC and it be as if I was in front of the original PC.  Both Hard drives will still be being used.

What is the best process for achieving this result?  And can this be done while PCA is booted into Lubuntu and the drive for PCB is connected via USB, or would this need to be completed from a Rescue or Live CD?

Comment: `rsync` is what you are looking for.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync

Comment: I see rsync is great for backing up files/folders but how would I clone the entire drive?

Comment: Please note that you have to change some things after cloning the drive (UUIDs for example). https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/full_system_backup_with_rsync

Comment: I get an error.  "The site can not be reached" when clicking the link or googling and trying to get to it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing the  `clonezilla` iso onto my flash drive and setting my computer to boot from my flash drive.  Then I followed the tutorial below to use a disk to disk option of `clonezilla`

[Clonezilla Disk To Disk How To](http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone)